# How can I get files off of a Mac when the display is broken?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, filevault, encryption

I need to get files off of my mac, and SSH and RDP are both disabled. My screen is broken, and my SSD is encrypted by FileVault.

Now, I do have one advantage: An external monitor. However, it will not turn on until FileVault has decrypted the hard drive. I have a BIOS password on it as well.

If there is a way to automatically select a user at the FileVault screen by pressing Enter or so, then please tell me. What I think I need to do is boot into Single User Mode, but I need to know exactly what prompts I'll encounter until it will display on the external monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is based on your comment about having two users.

I have Mountain Lion with two users and tried a reboot here.  On the login screen (where you normally click the user to enter the password), it seems you can press "Alt+I " (in your case) to get the password prompt for the user that has a name starting with "I" (in my case either Alt+M or Alt+S).

After pressing Enter, the field for the password opens, so you could type "password" and get to the desktop.

I don't know about File-Vault, or what it would look like, but if you know how to get to the User-Login screen without seeing it, the above will get you logged in and that may display the 2nd monitor.

(Regarding your other comment about it being hard to put the drive into a Mac-Mini, you don't need to put it "into" the Mac.  A cheap USB case will let you connect the drive to any computer or Mac via the USB port.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I would try this, but the Apple people have my laptop now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is boot the Mac in target mode (hold the T key down) and connect it via Thunderbolt or Firewire to another Mac so you can have visibility without repairing your Mac's screen. Alternatively, you could just remove the drive from the Mac and use a cheap $5 USB to SATA connector to mount the volume on a Mac to enter the Filevault passphrase to decrypt the volume.

Presumably, your system isn't booting since even in the blind, you should remember if you have to type in a user name and then press tab or return and then type the password.

User selection works by arrow keys and the space bar will select the user (and if you only have one user enabled to unlock the FileVault drive, you boot to a password screen so you only need to enter the password and press enter).

You can type the first letter of the user account and then type the password to get logged in. This assumes your user doesn't share a first letter with another account that is sorted before yours. In this case type the letter and then arrow key over to the second, third account and then type the password.

Comment: Regarding your third paragraph, I've always had to choose a user between Ian Carroll and Other

Comment: Ok, adding on to this: Is there a way to boot into single user mode, and if I succeed: 1) Will I need to enter a BIOS pass 2) Will it display on the 2nd monitor. I can't use your existing solution because I lack a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable.

Comment: Enabling FileVault means that neither is there a single user mode (it bypasses the security) nor any networking until you authenticate as a user that has a key to decrypt the core storage volume. The Mac runs in EFI firmware mode enough to determine which user accounts are allowed to decrypt and only starts booting OS X once you have authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you tagged your post with MacBook Air, I assume that this is the Mac you are talking about. Thus, target disk mode is not an option.* EDIT: I assume you have one of the early MacBook Air models, which don't support target disk mode.

As far as I know, there is no way to boot into recovery mode (which supports external screens), if you haven't unlocked your Mac with your firmware password before.

Some startup key combinations that you can use when your Mac starts, such as those which use the Option or Command keys, may not respond if a firmware password has also been enabled.

If you have a firmware password enabled on your Mac, you must successfully enter that password before you can boot to another startup volume, or before you can access the Startup Manager.

So the only solution I can think of is to get the drive out our your MacBook and mount it externally through a docking station on another Mac.

Comment: To clarify one thing: I know my firmware password, and have unlocked it before. It's relatively hard to put the drive in a Mac Mini.

Comment: A good way to connect your internal drive is a USB docking station. Most can take 3.5 and 2.5 drives and come rather cheap (30 U$). You can plug in your drive there and connect the docking station to your Mac Mini.

Answer (score 0):

To get the initial output on your external monitor you need to do this:-

1. Plug in the external monitor, and ensure it's on.
2. Open the (powered off) macbook lid
3. Hit the mac power button, and immediately (fast as you can) close the lid

So long as the lid is closed right from the start, it will use the external output properly.  If you hear the chime and the lid is open, it will *not* use the external output until after the O/S boots.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you have not used Time Machine to keep all data in case this happens.
I have just received my wife's MacbookAir with a cracked screen, she has backed up with Time Machine, all i do now is get a new machine and load it from her back up drive. First i connected it to an external screen then connected using Thunderbolt to HDMI port on my tv. Problem solved. Please use back up on your machines.